# Get multi store data in opencart

Tags: opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.6.4 and I've made a multi store named store1.mystore.com.

My question is, how to echo my multi store name (named My Tools Store) in store1.mystore.com footer page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
 <?php echo $this->config->get('config_name');?>
```